# web server scripting in python - maintaining state

Tags: python, uwsgi

I'm building a small web server based on nginx + uWSGI and running cgi scripts in python, but (probably 'cos I'm also using pyro) the execution time is over 1/2 second (it is on a Raspberry pi).  I need to run the python code so it maintains state between requests which should dramatically improve the performance. How can I do this?

I suspect the answer needs to be something along the lines of running python so it loops, pulling the requests off a queue, but I cannot find out how to do this.

Here is the trivial script - about 600ms to execute, the other end of the pyro remoted class is on the same machine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Pyro4
import logging

import cgi
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()

camuri = "PYRONAME:camerapi:cameraserv"`
camlist = Pyro4.Proxy(camuri)

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
clist = camlist.cameraList()

print("<h3>List of cameras</h3>")

for i in clist:
    acam = clist[0]
    print("<p>Camera: %d %s</p>" % (acam['ind'], acam['name']))
```

Comment: Pyro itself is not causing the delays. It's the cgi way of accessing your script that's slow.  Note that since Pyro 4.33, you can run a builtin http gateway to directly expose Pyro objects (via json) over http. See http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/tipstricks.html#pyro-via-http-and-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using CGI. There is no reason to do this.

Your desired behaviour is exactly how WSGI works. You should use that.

Comment: Ah! terse but to the point! actually found flask as a result of this, and it comes with a nice looking template framework as well

Comment: Thumbs-up to Flask, that'll do exactly what you want.